# Conditional Formatting +1 in Excel

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I want to apply conditional formatting to all cells that contain +1. To avoid Excel from converting +1 to 1 I used '+1. However, the below code does not work. Any ideas why?

```
my_formats = {-1: '#FF0000',
              "'+1": '#00FF00',}

for val, color in my_formats.items():
    fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_color': color})
    worksheet.conditional_format('B3:EK500', {'type': 'cell',
                                           'criteria': '=',
                                           'value': val,
                                           'format': fmt})
```

Comment: How about using a number format to add the `+` sign instead of making the cell into text? Don't know if that can be set via Python, though, but in Excel it would be the custom number format `+0;-0;0;@` -

Comment: Good idea but I also have regular 1s that should not be formatted the same way as the +1s. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ehrmm - use the format only the numbers that you want to show with a + sign.

Comment: I had to assign 1.1 to the cells where I wanted the +1. Then I applied the custom format you suggested, which worked. Thanks!